# How can I implement "Breadth First Search" in this code?

Tags: python, graph

I need to implement "Breast first search" in the code below.

It doesn't work because there's an error outside of my mind

.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/psh93/.spyder-py3/Breadth_First_Search.py', wdir='C:/Users/psh93/.spyder-py3')

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/psh93/.spyder-py3/Breadth_First_Search.py", line 51, in 
    graph.BFS(1)

File "C:/Users/psh93/.spyder-py3/Breadth_First_Search.py", line 33, in BFS
    queue.append(self.E[n])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

.

Here's my code.

```
class Vertex:

    def __init__(self, ID=0, data=None):
        self.id = ID
        self.data = data
        self.Visited = False

class Graph:

    def __init__(self):
        self.V = {}
        self.E = {}

    def addVertex(self, vertex=None):
        if vertex == None: return

        self.V[vertex.id] = vertex
        self.E[vertex.id] = []

    def addEdge(self, start_id=None, end_id=None):
        if start_id == None or end_id == None: return

        self.E[start_id].append(end_id)

    def BFS(self, first):
        #queue = [first]
        #visited = []

        #while queue:
            #n = queue.pop(0)
            #if n not in visited:
                #visited.append(n)
                #queue.append(self.E[n])

        #print(visited)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    graph = Graph()

    vertices = [(1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C"), (4, "D"), (5, "E"), (6, "F"), (7, "G")]
    edges = [(1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,6), (4,5), (4,7), (5,7), (6,7)]

    for (idx, data) in vertices:
        v = Vertex(idx, data)
        graph.addVertex(v)

    for (s, e) in edges:
        graph.addEdge(s, e)

    graph.BFS(1)
```

The area marked # is where the problem is.

```
def BFS(self, first)
```

No touch code except BFS

the output of

```
graph.BFS(1)
```

I'd like to get 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 > 6 > 7.

How can I have to do?

Thank you for reading the long code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `unhasable type: list` may means that you have dictionary and you use list as key in dictionary. But dictionary can't use list because it is not hashable. Use tuple instead of list as key in dictionary because tuple is hashable.

Comment: Well, then, can't I implement it using dict, TnT? Thank you for the comments.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - especially in line which you have in error message `queue.append(self.E[n])`. If you use `print(n)` then you see that it has `[2,3]` so you do `self.E[  [2,3]  ]` but list `[2,3]` can't be used as key in dictionary. You may have to convert to tuple `self.E[ tuple(n) ]` but when `n = 1` then `tuple(1)` will give error - and you would have to use list `[1]` instead single value `1`. SO you should check all your code - use `print()` for this.

Comment: or maybe you need list comprehension `[self.E[x] for x in n]`

Comment: Ah, "breast first search." Yeah, that is always happening in my mind.